# How to solve Status = 17, Index = 1, Status Text = Not writable?

Tags: snmp

I am using SNMP4J client to access the SNMP SET method https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/SNMP_Plugin:Getting_Started#SNMP_SET
which use to update the OIDs.

As mention in http://www.it-slav.net/blogs/2009/02/05/install-and-configure-snmp-on-ubuntu/, I installed snmp.

I set the community as "rwcommunity  private" in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`

Eventhough I am getting the below error

> Status = 17, Index = 1, Status Text = Not writable

How to resolve this?

Comment: You need to share your code, otherwise people will not able to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP error status 17, means that the object you are trying to set exists, but it is not writable. 
It all depends on what object you are trying to set and whether it is actually writable.

Comment: To set the writable permission, I set the community as "rwcommunity private" in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf. Is this correct? or could you please explain how can I set the permission?

Comment: @NirthikaRajendran Basically what that does, is that it allows writing when using that community, so it allows you to set values. Not every object is, however, writable. You could, for instance, have an object which contains the CPU temperature. There is no reasonable expectation for that to be writable. What object are you trying to set?

Comment: @LOvanIngen Thanks for the response, I am trying to update the oid **{"oid":"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0","value":"peters@it-slav.net","type":"String"}**

Comment: I'm no expert of running snmpd on a Ubuntu server; but do the file permissions of your /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf allow for writing by your snmpd-process?

Comment: @LOvanIngen I changed the file permissions of the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf to allow for writing and tried again, but I got same error.

Comment: @NirthikaRajendran Just to be sure; your SET-request does use the community 'private' and not 'public'? If not, than that's your problem. If yes, then I'm out of ideas and I would suggest reaching out to the writer of the tutorial...

Comment: Only a wireshark capture would prove what you are actually sending.